# opencv imread not found or imread not return value [ imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR); ]

Tags: opencv

opencv imread not found or imread not return value. imread not return value or give error imread NOT FOUND in Opencv (visual Studio 2010)

```
Mat image;
image = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   // Read the file

if(! image.data )                              // Check for invalid input
{
    cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
    return -1;
}

namedWindow( "Display window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// Create a window for display.
imshow( "Display window", image );                   // Show our image inside it.

waitKey(0);                                          // Wait for a keystroke in the window
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Don't get the downvotes wrong. We need to see the code to help you out

Comment: Hello VusP ! Give me reply for this...

Comment: jpaari has put it well

Comment: @VusP I agree, I don't get them as well

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the image file format is one of the supported types (http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imread). Also ensure that the filepath given as the argument is correct. You could also use drag & drop the image on the executable file.