# OpenCV Tutorial: Load and Display an Image (codeblocks, fedora20)

Tags: c++, opencv, codeblocks

I successfully installed and linked and included OpenCV. (I know it was successful because I compiled and ran the opencv program [found on this site](http://opencv.blogspot.com/2005/03/my-first-opencv-program.html))

So I went back to the OpenCV documentation and tutorials pages. I copied [from this page](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html) the exact code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if( argc != 2)
    {
        cout <<" Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    Mat image;
    image = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   // Read the file

    if(!image.data )                              // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow( "Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// Create a window for display.
    imshow( "Display window", image );                   // Show our image inside it.

    waitKey(0);                                          // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
//This is the end
```

(Running codeblocks on fedora20)
Using Project >> Set programs' arguments I fed in "/home/Kennedy/Pictures/enterprise.bmp" without the quotes.

Since I'm using a bmp file ([supported](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imread)), and the file path is correct, can anyone suggest why codeblocks is spitting out

```
/home/Kennedy/Documents/workspace/OpenCVtest/main.cpp|21|error: ‘CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR’ was not declared in this scope|
```

instead of running a lovely little first program?

For reference, I've read but not found help on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19923463/opencv-imread-not-found-or-imread-not-return-value-imreadargv1-cv-load-ima), [this](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imread), and other Q&As on stackoverflow, codeblocks forum, and anywhere else I could think to look. I also saw [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/25827/cv_load_image_color-not-defined-in-this-scope/), but I'm not having a problem with WINDOW_AUTOSIZE.

EDIT TO ADD ANOTHER ATTEMPTED SOLUTION:
I copied and pasted enterprise.bmp to the folder containing the project, removed the arguments, and replaced argv[1](http://opencv.blogspot.com/2005/03/my-first-opencv-program.html) with "enterprise.bmp".  This had no effect, I still get the same error.

Comment: try this... imread(argv[1], 1);

Comment: What version of OpenCV did You installed? 0.9.2? Why? OpenCV is now 2.4.9

Comment: @thedarksideofthemoon Where did you get 0.9.2? I have version 2.4.7, and its [tutorial link](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.7/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html) uses the CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR as well.

Comment: Sorry, my bad... How did you install OpenCV? git clone?

Comment: Got it out of the fedora repo, yum install. (and you don't need to apologize, I just wanted to make sure I didn't include something that implied a zero-point version)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

That means you're likely compiling against opencv 3.0. The symbol "CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR" has been replaced with "cv::IMREAD_COLOR". Just edit the file and you should be good. It's the only deprecated symbol used in Caffe.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue when I installed ubuntu and opencv.

I tried to change the header include file as below, the problem is solved and run successfully.

But I don't know why , who can help ?

My change is comment out opencv.hpp header file and add cv.h and highgui_c.h ...

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h>
//#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

Comment: ah, no, falling back to the c-api is the worst idea ever. also, this is not an answer. please start your own question!

Comment: why deduct my score, I just mentioned I use the c-api can solve problem but didn't promote this way, that's why I am also asking. And about raising a new question, I think this is quite similar question, combine my question together with this one is better than opening a new one, try image you search a lot of similar questions, how it help you solve your problem.